# asp.net web.config authorization attributes working in visual studio, but not on publish

Tags: asp.net, web.sitemap, aspmenu-control

Thanks for any help.

**Edit** 
this has been altered from the initial question, as no answers had been posted, and the problem evolved in more detail

I am trying to complete an asp.net 4.0 web application. I am struggling to manage folder based authorization.

a sample of the XML from the web.config:

```
<location path="~/drugAdmin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="drugAdmin" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/wardAdmin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="wardAdmin" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/websiteAdmin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="websiteAdmin" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/personalAccount">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

The authorization works beautifully when the web application is started via visual studio.

when I publish to a local directory on my machine with the same web.config file, the authorization allows anonymous users into the wardAdmin and personalAccount folders ONLY (ie works appropriately for the other folders).

Has anyone come accross a similar problem and know a solution? thanks

Comment: Are they both running under the same web server, or are they running under separate web servers (IIS vs. IIS Express or Cassini in VS)?

Comment: the working version is visual studio development server, and the published version (with the problems with permissions) gives the same erroneous behavior under IIS 7.5 and I IIS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing the tildes fixed the problem

```
<location path="drugAdmin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="drugAdmin" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```